# Even after disabling some tabs from admin , it still comes on frontend

Tags: product, tabs, magento2.2-dev

[image: want to hide two tabs]

I want to hide two tabs . as per theme guide  i disabled them from admin pannel.
[image: disabled tabs].

It still comes on frontend.

```
<div class="group-title1 title-tab">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <?php 
                $tab_contents = $block->getTabContent() ; 

            $count=0;           
            foreach($tab_contents as $tab) {
                ?>
            <li rel="tab_<?php echo $tab['id'];?>"  class="<?php if ($count==0): ?>first active<?php endif; ?>" > <?php echo $tab['name'];?></li>
                <?php
                $count ++; 
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

This is the section in phtml which shows tabs name.

My question is how to check that weather the loop depends on admin on/off event or its just shows all the three tabs by default.

I can hide them by css but i want to debug this.

Any suggestions.

Comment: can you share the code of the block class for this template and system.xml of this module. The information above is not sufficient to answer the question

Comment: Sure , I will update my question soon, once I have access to this file again on Monday.